# Elegant way to filter duplicates in one column and by values of a second column

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with about 20 columns.  Column A is numeric.  Column B is alphanumeric.  I want to filter out rows whose values in Column A are below a threshold.  At the same time, I want to filter out rows whose values in Column B are duplicates of earlier values in Column B.

There are many ways to do this.  But I am looking for an "elegant" way: a way that doesn't require pivot tables, conditional formatting, or the creation of an additional column.  Is there a way that meets these criteria?

A number of posts speak to related ideas.  But I haven't found any that speak directly to this problem.

Comment: You will need one column with unique values that can be used to identify the second (or third) values from column B.

Comment: The most elegant way is to make an additional column. Criterion for column B is beyond standard column filtering functionality.

Comment: Add a formula-based conditional format onto the column with duplicates - eg. to add a solid fill for all cells which are duplicates of an earlier row (you can use `Countif()` ).  You can then filter on that column (by color) in addition to the other filter (by value)  EDIT - never mind I just saw that "no conditional formatting". Seems you'll need to write some VBA.